# Create Chaikin Oscillator using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, technical-indicator

I'm trying to implement Chaikin Oscillator from scratch but it gives me wrong results comparing to real one API (TradingView for example)

Code:

```
def exponential_moving_average_series(ts, n):
    """
    :param df: pandas.DataFrame
    :param n:
    :return: pandas.DataFrame
    """
    EMA = pd.Series(pd.ewma(ts, span = n, min_periods = n - 1), name = 'EMA_' + str(n))
    return EMA


def chaikin_oscillator(df):
    """Calculate Chaikin Oscillator for given data.
    :param df: pandas.DataFrame
    :return: pandas.DataFrame
    """
    ad = (2 * df['Close'] - df['High'] - df['Low']) * df['Volume'] / (df['High'] - df['Low'])
    ad = ad + ad.shift(1)

    ema3 = exponential_moving_average_series(ad,3);
    ema10 = exponential_moving_average_series(ad,10);

    Chaikin = pd.Series((ema3-ema10), name='Chaikin')

    df = df.join(Chaikin)
    return df
```

Results:

[Chaikin oscillator from this code comparing to asset's closing positions graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYXuT.png)

[Chaikin oscillator reference from TradingView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/519D5.png)

Data formatted as:

> index Timestamp   Open    Close   High    Low Volume  Chaikin

Comment: Specific implementations of ewm windows can vary--see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-windows

Comment: Also, you might want to switch to `ts.ewm(...).mean()` as I believe what you have now is deprecated

Comment: @BradSolomon thanks, I believe I've used the same EMA as required by Chaikin oscillator formula. Also it will still output the same wrong curve if I switch from ewma() to ts.ewm().mean() so the error doesn't depend on it I think. (I'm sorry for attaching deprecated methods in question code)

Comment: What stock/security is this for?

Comment: @BradSolomon it's for crypto indices. Actually I've just now managed to successfully run TA-lib and it's performing Chaikin osc really well (identical to reference), so it appears it's not about some kind of different implementations of the indicator

Answer (score 0):

Volume-based indicators are impractical to match TradingView because the reported volume data can often be different. With crypto the volume is also exchange-specific. With the Chaikin Oscillator, even more complications exist due to a seemingly undefined lookback length.

As of 2022, [one article](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/chaikinoscillator.asp) on Investopedia says to use `ADL=M(Period−1)+M(Period)`. Also as of 2022, [another article](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/active-trading/031914/understanding-chaikin-oscillator.asp) says "the running total generates the acc/dis line", implying `ADL=ADL(Period-1)+M(Period)` or equivalently `ADL=M.cumsum()` instead. The two approaches are not the same. The first definition has a more repeatable calculation since it has a finite lookback period of 2 for summation, but it does a very poor job at matching TradingView v28 in even its sign or direction. The second definition has a less repeatable calculation since it has an undefined lookback period for summation, but it does a far better job at matching TradingView v28. Note that the formula specified by [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000501979-chaikin-oscillator/) uses the second approach.

```py
from typing import Optional

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def ema(s: pd.Series, period: int = 9) -> pd.Series:
    return s.ewm(span=period).mean()


def chaikin_oscillator(df: pd.DataFrame, *, ad_lookback: Optional[int] = None) -> pd.Series:
    """Return the Chaikin Oscillator.
    
    Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74280142/
    
    :param ad_lookback: Accumulation/Distribution summation lookback period.
        If None, the lookback is unbounded but is less repeatable across inputs of varying lengths. 
        For a more repeatable result, consider a value such as 100, 200, 300, etc.
    """
    # Calculate money flow volume:
    money_flow_multiplier = ((df['close'] - df['low']) - (df['high'] - df['close'])) / (df['high'] - df['low'])
    money_flow_volume = money_flow_multiplier * df['volume']

    # Refine money flow volume:
    # This is as per TradingView's calculation of Accumulation/Distribution v27.
    money_flow_volume = np.where((df['close'] == df['high']) & (df['close'] == df['low']) | (df['high'] == df['low']), 0, money_flow_volume)
    money_flow_volume = pd.Series(money_flow_volume, index=df.index)

    # Calculate Accumulation/Distribution:
    accumulation_distribution_line = money_flow_volume.cumsum() if (ad_lookback is None) else money_flow_volume.rolling(ad_lookback).sum()

    # Calculate Chaikin Oscillator:
    co = ema(accumulation_distribution_line, 3) - ema(accumulation_distribution_line, 10)
    return co
```

A third-party package such as [`pandas-ta`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-ta/) can alternatively be used to return effectively the same values as above (assuming `ad_lookback=None`). If using the `ta.adosc` function of this package, I would strictly avoid providing `open_=df['open']`, otherwise the returned values do much worse at matching TradingView.

```py
import pandas_ta as ta

chaikin_oscillator = ta.adosc(high=df['high'], low=df['low'], close=df['close'], volume=df['volume'], fast=3, slow=10)
```